# Error while calling location coordinates in the doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps

I'm trying to send data to server using `AsyncTask` method.

I'm getting all the other device information and userdetails.

However, when I try to get the `location coordinates` within the `try catch` in the `doInBackground`, 
I get the following error:

> **java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

Any help is highly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

Here is my class in which **`AsyncTask`** is applied..

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if (fieldsValidation().equals("ok")) {
                    if (Check_Internet_Con.isConnectingToInternet(getActivity())) { 
                        new PostSignOnDuty().execute(); 
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    errorMsg.showErrorMsg(getActivity(), view, fieldsValidation());
                }
    }

    private class PostSignOnDuty extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Submitting Details..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            dutyId = sharedPreference.getDutyTypeId();
            userId = sharedPreference.getUserId();
            deviceId = simAndDeviceId.getDeviceId();
            stnCode = selectStn.getText().toString();
            signOnComments = edtPurpose.getText().toString();
            btnSignOn.setClickable(false);
            btnSignOn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            try {
                if (coordinates.getLocation() != null) {
                    latitute = coordinates.getLocation().getLatitude();
                    longitute = coordinates.getLocation().getLongitude();
                    Get_Address get_address = new Get_Address(getActivity(), latitute, longitute);
                    city = get_address.getCity();
                    state = get_address.getState();
                    area = get_address.getArea();
                    completeAddress = get_address.getCompleteAddress();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String Url_Sign_On_Duty = getResources().getString(R.string.Url_Sign_On_Duty);

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", String.valueOf(userId)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stationcode", stnCode));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DutyId", String.valueOf(dutyId)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteTypeId", "0"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Area", area));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("City", city));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("State", state));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Address", completeAddress));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", signOnComments));
            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
            String json = jsonParser.makeGetServiceCall(Url_Sign_On_Duty, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            loginStatusTime = Integer.parseInt(result);
            sharedPreference.setLoginstatusid(loginStatusTime);
            sharedPreference.setActiveUserId(1);
            if (loginStatusTime > 0) {
                try {
                    if (coordinates.getLocation() != null) {
                        coordinates.getLocation();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                /*getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), GPS_Service.class));
                getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), Send_Records_Service.class));*/
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have Signed on at " + stnCode + " at " + getSignOnTime() + " hours", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignOfDuty.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is My Location Class..

```
public android.location.Location getLocation() throws IOException {
        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // location service disabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, SIXTY_SECONDS,
                            0, this);

                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (mLocationManager != null) {
                        location = mLocationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        //updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }

                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                SIXTY_SECONDS,
                                0, this);

                        Log.d("Network", "Network");

                        if (mLocationManager != null) {
                            location = mLocationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            //updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Location",
                    "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }


        return location;
    }
```

Comment: " btnSignOn.setClickable(false);" .. You can not access Ui elements from background thread. Do the all Ui related tasks in OnPreExecute() .

Comment: @ADM, tried but not working

Comment: Did you Remove all Ui related lines from doInBackground()? getText() one too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform actions on **`UI Thread`** from **`doInBackground()`** method. Because **Android UI toolkit** is not **`thread-safe`**. So, you should not manipulate your **`UI`** from a worker thread

**[From Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)**

Use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)

       }
});
```

Your **`doInBackground`** should be-:,

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {                        
                dutyId = sharedPreference.getDutyTypeId();
                userId = sharedPreference.getUserId();
                deviceId = simAndDeviceId.getDeviceId();
                stnCode = selectStn.getText().toString();
                signOnComments = edtPurpose.getText().toString();
                btnSignOn.setClickable(false);


        btnSignOn.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        try {
            if (coordinates.getLocation() != null) {
                latitute = coordinates.getLocation().getLatitude();
                longitute = coordinates.getLocation().getLongitude();
                Get_Address get_address = new Get_Address(getActivity(), latitute, longitute);
                city = get_address.getCity();
                state = get_address.getState();
                area = get_address.getArea();
                completeAddress = get_address.getCompleteAddress();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
            });
        String Url_Sign_On_Duty = getResources().getString(R.string.Url_Sign_On_Duty);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", String.valueOf(userId)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceid", deviceId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stationcode", stnCode));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DutyId", String.valueOf(dutyId)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteTypeId", "0"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Area", area));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("City", city));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("State", state));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Address", completeAddress));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", signOnComments));
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeGetServiceCall(Url_Sign_On_Duty, ServiceHandler.POST, params);
        return json;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure but this may help you

```
 if (isGPSEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, SIXTY_SECONDS,
                        0, this,Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Comment: yes..i tried like this.
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)
                    btnSignOn.setClickable(false);
                }
            });

Comment: try to wrap all string value in your runonuithread as in my updated answer

Comment: When the get coordinates function tries to get location from the Location Class, it throws the exception of java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() 
 in   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, SIXTY_SECONDS,
                            0, this);

Comment: or you should not update these value inside doInBackground() method try to update these variable outside the doInBackgroung like in OnCreate() method

Comment: @user7348352 it's better to set view onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). As you learnt from tutorails, since you are using progressBar in those methods, that's why those methods are for. They run on UI thread while doInBackground() runs in a separate thread. It's not wrong to use runOnUIThread but proper way is to use other methods and it's more consistent with rest of the code for setting progressBar.

Comment: @user mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, SIXTY_SECONDS, 0, **this**); is why you get the error. You should either register on UI thread or create a HandlerThread or a Thread with Looper

Comment: Yeah exactly you should wrap up  try {
            if (coordinates.getLocation() != null) { to runOnUIhtread or try the above edited answer

Comment: @user7348352 I have update my answer try doInBackground thread code this may help you

Comment: @user7348352, edited answer is also not exactly correct . I'm shouting it even you were pointing other direction it's about a Thread without Looper from the beginning. You should also not request location updates every time you need to get location, it's not correct and it's how you create memory leaks. You should register a listener `onResume()` and unregister it `onPause()`.

Comment: @FatihOzcan you can see I had put a code with `Looper` in **EDIT** section inside my answer `if (isGPSEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, SIXTY_SECONDS,
                        0, this,Looper.getMainLooper());`

Comment: @FatihOzcan If I'm calling in the onResume(), it takes time to load up which was the reason for trying it in a thread

Comment: You should call mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mListener) some where in your code without loosing reference to mListener.  mListener is the class that implements LocationListener. Unregistered listeners cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You must not to disable a `button` `doInBackground()` method. `onPreExecute()` is there for it. Disable a `button` `onPreExecute()`, and enable it again `onPostExecute()`, all of the tutorials on the web suggests you do this way, also you are setting  `progressBar` in those methods some in `doInBackground()` while setting button other way.

Your issue is not about that. It's about a `Thread` not having a `Looper` and trying to send message or `postRunnable` without `Looper`. You are requesting updates in Thread of AsyncTask. Instead you should request it on UI thread but not inside a method every time you request location update. Listeners or callbacks must be registered `onResume()` and unregistered `onPause()` methods.

Comment: It throws the exception even before the ServiceHandler() is called

Comment: You may be registering LocationManager in a different Thread but without starting a Looper or without using a HandlerThread.